# sendmail issue from uniVerse phantom generated script

Tags: linux, universe

Not quite sure what is happening here. If I run my script from a Universe basic program no problems under a user login, email is sent and received. However if I run it as a background process I get the following error

```
Saved message in /home/batch31/dead.letter
```

Do I need to setup the Batchs (i.e. phantoms) somewhere in linux? Can't quite follow the instructions the linux experts are tossing about.

Platform Linux uniVerse 10.3 information flavor.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Actually it is about a programming issue, perhaps if you had experience in Universe or any other post relational database you would recognise that. Haven't posted any code yet in the question because this one runs through a main program, a subroutine, and a script generation program.

Comment: ScaryMinds,

Could use a bit more information, my first thought is that it has to do with the script that is sending the email.  Is the error about the saved messages part of your code, or the code that sends the email?  Note I am assuming this was in the &PH& file, and not displayed on the clients screen.

Mike

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike, it definitely has something to do with the phantoms, works fine from my login and a colleagues login. Will post up the universe code that generates the bash script, have a vague notion I might need to add something into the script generation.